# tgz -ubuntu file type

Tags: files, android-studio

I'm new in Ubuntu and I have a question to ask:

I wanna download a file the his type is: tgz. For example: androidstudio.tgz

and in the site that's says: For Linux.

Is it gonna work on Ubuntu?

Comment: That question applies to .tgz's also.

Comment: I dont think so. I asked if is it work. Because in the site:
https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html
It writes: For Linux

Comment: Answer is yes. It will work.

Comment: Linux covers a broad range of OS'es. Ubuntu, Debian, OpenSuse, RedHat, etc.